# Bash Select position of array element by args

Tags: bash

I want make a bash script which returns the position of an element from an array by give an arg. See code below, I use:

```
#!/bin/bash
args=("$@")
echo ${args[0]}
test_array=('AA' 'BB' 'CC' 'DD' 'EE')
echo $test_array
elem_array=${#test_array[@]}
for args in $test_array
do
        echo 
done
```

Finally I should have output like:

```
$script.sh DD
4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to avoid complex tools:

```
test_array=('AA' 'BB' 'CC' 'D D' 'EE')
OLD_IFS="$IFS"
IFS="
"
element=$(grep -n '^D D$' <<< "${test_array[*]}" | cut -d ":" -f 1)
IFS="$OLD_IFS"
echo $element
```

However, it consumes 2 processes.  If we allow ourselves `sed`, we could do it with a single process:

```
test_array=('AA' 'BB' 'CC' 'D D' 'EE')
OLD_IFS="$IFS"
IFS="
"
element=$(sed -n -e '/^D D$/=' <<< "${test_array[*]}")
IFS="$OLD_IFS"
echo $element
```

**Update:**

As pointed out by thkala in the comments, this solution is broken in 3 cases.  Be careful not to use it if:

1. You want zero indexed offset.
2. You have newlines in your array elements.
3. And you have a sparse array, or have other keys than integers.

Comment: This is broken in two respects: 1. it has an off-by-one error, since bash arrays are zero-based - although the OP also wants a one-based index. 2. it assumes that array indexes are contiguous, while they are not - it will break completely if there are gaps in the array index assignments or if some elements have been unset...

Comment: True, true, and true: Aoutch !  I will try to remember that arrays in bash are truly maps.  But as poster seams to like the answer, I will not delete it, but I will update it to point out the limitations you found.

Answer (score 7):

```
#!/bin/bash

A=(AA BB CC DD EE)

for i in "${!A[@]}"; do
        if [[ "${A[i]}" = "$1" ]]; then
                echo "$i"
        fi
done
```

Note the `"${!A[@]}"` notation that gives the list of valid indexes in the array. In general you cannot just go from 0 to `"${#A[@]}" - 1`, because the indexes are not necessarily contiguous. There can be gaps in the index range if there were gaps in the array element assignments or if some elements have been unset.

The script above will output all indexes of the array for which its content is equal to the first command line argument of the script.

**EDIT:**

In your question, you seem to want the result as a one-based array index. In that case you can just increment the result by one:

```
#!/bin/bash

A=(AA BB CC DD EE)

for i in "${!A[@]}"; do
        if [[ "${A[i]}" = "$1" ]]; then
                let i++;

                echo "$i"
        fi
done
```

Keep in mind, though, that this index will have to be *decremented* before being used with a zero-based array.

Answer (score 1):

Loop over the array and keep track of the position. 
When you find the element matching the input argument, print out the position of the element. You need to add one to the position, because arrays have zero-based indexing.

```
#! /bin/sh
arg=$1
echo $arg
test_array=('AA' 'BB' 'CC' 'DD' 'EE')
element_count=${#test_array[@]}
index=0

while [ $index -lt $element_count ]
do    
  if [ "${test_array[index]}" = "$arg" ]
  then
     echo $((index+1))
     break
  fi
  ((index++))
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Without loop:

```
#!/bin/bash

index() {
    local IFS=$'\n';
    echo "${*:2}" | awk '$0 == "'"${1//\"/\\\"}"'" { print NR-1; exit; }'
}

array=("D A D" "A D" bBb "D WW" D "\" D \"" e1e " D " E1E D AA "" BB)
element=${array[5]}
index "$element" "${array[@]}"
```

Output:

```
5
```